# Ant is stripping out color formatting of a command, can I get it back?

Tags: bash, ant

I'm using Ant's `exec` to invoke an external command. Because of the way Ant processes SDTOUT from commands, the colorized output from the command is stripped out. Is there any way to preserve the color formatting of the original command?

Comment: Which external command?

Comment: In my case, it is behat (www.behat.org), which normally outputs ANSI color-formatted text.

Comment: According to the docs (http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html), behat has a `--color` option, which suggests that it colorizes automatically based on whether stdout is a terminal or not. I suggest you use `behat --color` to force colorization, as the docs indicate.

Answer (score 1):

What we did is to write a custom ant logger to colorize log output. However, this was adding color to plain logging based on the ant log level, rather than passing through existing ANSI color codes in the underlying output.

You might first check where the stripping is happening. I've stepped through the code before but don't remember see anything other than some modification of newline constructs (eg `\r` replaced by `\n`). It could be that the underlying command detects that it is not connected to a TTY when run under ant and disables colorization itself - a fairly common behavior for processes that can output ANSI color codes.